# Could you explain the use of would in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

If I replace it with "will" or "is", is there any difference?

> Question A: I've tied the knot for 42 years. It's incredible. The time pass so quickly. Is this sentence right?

> Answer B: The expression "tie the knot" means to get married - the ceremony itself, so in your sentence it **would** be I/we tied the knot 42 years ago

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Neither sentence is very idiomatic English. _The time has passed so quickly_ would be more natural, and I would expect **it should be**.